# Throw exception when value is not found in enum instead of returning nil

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I have an array, decoded from a JSON sent by my server.
I want, in one line of code, to retrieve the value of a node and transform it into a enum value.
Several error can occur : (1) node does not exist, (2) node value is not a string (my enums have only String raw values), or (3) the string provided doesn't fit any existing value in the enum.

For the moment, I made an extension of Dictionary that enable me to have (1) and (2) in one line for other things than enums, and propagate easily the error if it occurs :

```
struct MemberOptions : MyDecodable
{
    var name:String 
    var age:Int 
    var facebookAccount:FacebookAccount


    init(from array:[String:Any]) throws 
    {
        // throw exception if node name doesn't exist, is json<null> or if it's value is not castable to the providen parameter (raw types or more complex object implementing MyDecodable protocol)
        name = try array.getSafe("name", String.self)
        age = try array.getSafe("age", Int.self) 
        facebookAccount = try array.getSafe("fb", FacebookAccount.self) 

    }
   
}
```

Now comes the tricky part : I want (3) for enum, that is, propagate an error in one line if the provided string raw value is not a known enum value, for a given enum. I saw that the default init of an enum returns nil if the raw string value does not exist. I want it to throw an exception.

Of course, I could make an init for all my enums that would throw an exception, but it's not generic, it would be a redundant code. Of course I could do also in my business classes inits :

```
if let enumVal = MyEnum(rawValue: try array.getSafe("enumKey", String.self))
{
     self.enumVal = enumVal 
} 
else 
{
    throw ValueNotPresentException()
}
```

but still it wouldn't be generic enough, I would have to do write these 4 lines for every enum I want to retrieve.

What I'd like would be some shared function over all my enums something like `getSafely(raw: myRawString) throws` that would throw exception if raw value is not present, instead of returning nil. Then I could have (1) (2) and (3) in one line and not having to write redundant code :

```
enumProp = try EnumType.getSafely(fromRaw: try array.getSafely("key", String.self))
```

Is there any way to make such a generic system in Swift (using maybe enum protocols, or some reflection) ? How would you handle that ?

Comment: You get this behavior for free when you make a string-valued enum, like `enum Foo: String { ... }`

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you provide an exemple ? I saw the initialiser returns nil but does not throw an exception by default

Comment: Oh, true. Yeah as Leo shows, that's easily solved by extended `RawRepresentable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend `RawRepresentable` and create an initializer that throws an `Error` instead of returning `nil`:

```
enum Exception: Error {
    case valueNotPresent
}
```

---

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init(_ rawValue: RawValue) throws {
        guard let value = Self(rawValue: rawValue) else {
            throw Exception.valueNotPresent
        }
        self = value
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
enum FacebookAccount: String {
    case a, b, c
}

do {
    let fbAccount = try FacebookAccount("d")
    print(fbAccount)
} catch {
    print(error)  // "valueNotPresent\n"
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer that’s what I was looking for. Is it because all enum implements by default this raw représentable protocol ?

Comment: If a value (raw value) is provided for the enumeration it automatically conforms to the RawRepresentable protocol therefore they will share  the same fallible initializer.